# Convert rmi interface to CORBA .idl

Tags: java, corba

how can I convert my rmi interface into an .idl file in CORBA. Im currently working in a chat application. So here's my interface:

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface ChatServer extends Remote{
      void register(ChatClient c) throws RemoteException;
      void broadcast(String s) throws RemoteException;
}
```

I tried doing it but it said theres and error with the "void" and ChatClient being an undeclared type. How can I solve this? Thank you for your help :)

p.s I got the rmi code in the internet, I only need it as my reference so that I can convert it to CORBA application.

Comment: What is the `ChatClient` class or interface? BTW, CORBA is a dead technology, so, why are you interested on that?

Comment: It is an Interface same as the ChatServer, its kind of the same so I didnt include it. And for the CORBA, school stuff, my teacher want us to convert an RMI code that we see in the internet to a CORBA application.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to extend `java.io.Serializable`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ChatServer extends Remote, Serializable {
    void register(ChatClient c) throws RemoteException;
    void broadcast(String s) throws RemoteException;
}
```

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ChatClient extends Remote, Serializable {
    void register(ChatServer c) throws RemoteException;
    void broadcast(String s) throws RemoteException;
}
```

The reason for that all the parameters and all the non-void return types must be `Serializable` things. `String` is `Serializable`.

Other than that, this seems to be a very poor design. Those interfaces are intended to denote which are the operations offered by each endpoint. On the other hand, `Serializable` stuff are the data transfered between endpoints. By creating classes/objects/interfaces that uses both hats, it tends to surely become a big mess.

A better idea would be:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClientId implements Serializable {
   // Data used to identify the client.
}
```

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ServerId implements Serializable {
   // Data used to identify the server.
}
```

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ChatServer extends Remote {
    void register(ClientId c) throws RemoteException;
    void broadcast(String s) throws RemoteException;
}
```

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ChatClient extends Remote {
    void register(ServerId c) throws RemoteException;
    void broadcast(String s) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: it is a good tip for my program, unfortunately, I want to convert my interface as a CORBA .idl file, not in the RMI interface. So it doesnt answer my question :D.